# Select a document within the db.collection operation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, express

I'm new here on the site, I have a question regarding a function in nodejs that I am unable to resolve. The solution is very simple but it does not work for me.

I build a social network in React, and for that I use nodeJs.
I have one function that I try to fix, but it does not work.
In firebase I have a collection called match, and in it I have details of users, and for each user, appear the other participants who are his friends.
For example according to the picture:

[image]

I have a collection of Match, in it I have my users, for example backend4 is a user's name, and in it, I have details of all the users it is suitable for.

This is the function I wrote down, but there is a problem with it, that it goes through all the users, the three users that can be seen in the picture.

```
exports.getMatchHandleArray = (req, res) => {
  let engineers = [];

  db.collection("match").get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const engineerDetails = doc.data();
      if (engineerDetails.handle === req.user.handle) {
        engineerDetails.handle;
        engineers.unshift(engineerDetails);
      }
      else {
        engineerDetails.handle;
        engineers.push(engineerDetails);
      }
    });

    console.log(engineers.length);
    res.json(engineers);

  });
};
```

I want it to go through only one user I choose, for that I did something like this:

```
exports.getMatchHandleArray = (req, res) => {
  let engineers = [];

  db.collection(`/match/${req.user.handle}`).get().then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const engineerDetails = doc.data();
      if (engineerDetails.handle === req.user.handle) {
        engineerDetails.handle;
        engineers.unshift(engineerDetails);
      }
      else {
        engineerDetails.handle;
        engineers.push(engineerDetails);
      }
    });

    console.log(engineers.length);
    res.json(engineers);

  });
};
```

I get a 500 error message on this, I understand why, because I can not make a selection within db.collection.
I think something like this should be used:
db.doc (`/ match / $ {req.user.handle}`) but I can not do that

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.getMatchHandleArray = (req, res) => {

  let userData = {};
  db.doc(`/match/${req.user.handle}`)
    .get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        userData.match = doc.data();
      }
      return res.json(userData.match);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
};
```

i find the solution that's works for me